# How to measure the Fermi velocity in Dirac materials?

Tags: dirac-equation, graphene

Suppose that one has a Dirac material (e.g., graphene), i.e., a system where there exists a number $N$ of *identical* Dirac cones (linear dispersion) at the Fermi energy $E_F=0$. 
How can one measure the Fermi velocity $v_F$ of the Dirac cones? 
In other words, are there measurable quantities which depend directly on the Fermi velocity in Dirac materials, and how these quantities are related with $v_F$?
Is the ballistic conductance of such material, for example, related to the Fermi velocity?

Edit: please exclude the trivial case of measuring directly the band structure with spectroscopic techniques, like eg ARPES.

This question is directly related to the question [Are there measurable quantities which directly depends on the Fermi velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199449/are-there-measurable-quantities-which-directly-depends-on-the-fermi-velocity) (which has no satisfied answer so far).

Comment: I would think that the density of states should depend on the Fermi velocity, since it is the only parameter that characterizes the Dirac spectrum close to the Dirac point.

Comment: @MengCheng The density of states is indeed zero at the Dirac point. Consider the case at zero temperature.

Comment: Nope the density of states is not zero! The density of states is (for non-interacting systems) independent of the temperature! The occupation is $n_F(\epsilon - \mu) z(\epsilon)$ with the Fermi distribution (that is temperature dependent) and the density of states $z$. As you say, another method to measure this is ARPES (angle resolved photo emission spectroscopy), which more or less measures the density of states (or rather spectral funtion) directly. (But the density of states is viable as it is accessible via tunnelling experiments).

Comment: @SebastianRiese I never said that the density of states depends on the temperature. Anyway at the dirac point $\epsilon=\mu$ also the density of states vanishes (there is only a single 0D point at the Fermi level). Can you please elaborate about tunnelling?

Comment: My comment on the temperature it was meant to say that at zero temperature one can forget about what is above and below the dirac point. Although this is perhaps not correct (now that I am thinking about this) I never meant to say that the fermi velocity or the density of states depends on the temperature (although they can indeed depend if temperature induces phase transitions, but this is however another story...)

Comment: Setup: graphene <-> quantum dot <-> probe lead, where the "<->" denote tunnel contacts. The current is proportional to the the densities of states in graphene and the probe lead for small voltages (assuming that only the one-particle state of the quantum dot is energetically accessible due to Coulomb repulsion). By changing the probe lead voltage you can probe the density of states at different energies. Gauging the tunneling parameters might be difficult, however.

Comment: Also the low temperature thermodynamics should be determined only by the density of states (and thereby Fermi velocity), although I guess that calorimetry of graphene is difficult.

Comment: @sintetico And of course you are right that the density of states is zero at the Dirac point (I was thinking of the 1d case of linear dispersion, where the density of states is constant ...). But it is obviously non-zero near the Dirac point and this can be probed.

Comment: Ok maybe we are getting closer to an answer. The DOS near zero is related to $v_F$. Now, how one can probe the DOS near the Dirac point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33300/discussion-between-sebastian-riese-and-sintetico).